# How to integrate LESS into ZendFramework 2

Tags: namespaces, zend-framework2, less

I have found [this tutorial](https://stephen.rees-carter.net/thought/integrating-less-with-zend-framework-the-easy-way) which is for **ZendFramework 1**. I download less and put it under **project/vendor/**.

```
Leafo
└── Less
    ├── Lessc.php
    └── Lessify.php
```

In **project/module/Application/Module.php**

```
...
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    ...
    $this->compileLess();
}
...
public function compileLess()
{
    if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'production') {
        return;
    }
    require_once PROJECT_PATH . '/vendor/Leafo/Less/Lessc.php';

    $less_file = PROJECT_PATH . '/public/less/style.less';
    $css_file = PROJECT_PATH . '/public/css/style.css';

    $lessc = new \Leafo\Less\Lessc($less_file);
    file_put_contents($css_file, $lessc->parse());
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the error below

> Fatal error: Class 'Leafo\Less\Lessc' not found in /Users/jslim/public_html/littlepinktree/module/Application/Module.php on line 53

I have a few questions here:

1. How do I integrate 3rd party library to ZF2 (if the 3rd party library is not using namespace)?
2. Is there any example showing how to integrate [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to ZF2?

Comment: first check what is your PROJECT_PATH? if it till the public then use ../vendor

Comment: leafo/less can be installed with composer https://packagist.org/packages/leafo/lessphp You might also want to take a look at the assets-bundle zf2 module https://github.com/neilime/zf2-assets-bundle

Comment: @OSSCubeSolution PROJECT_PATH is defined in **public/index.php**. `defined('PROJECT_PATH') || define('PROJECT_PATH', __DIR__ . '/..');`.

Comment: @Crisp I was installed via composer, and I have no idea how to include it, so I rename all the files and the class name as well. Unfortunately, it still not able to use the namespace. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this by putting the whole director in **./module/Application/src/Less**

**NOTE: I used back the original structure as follow**

```
src
├── Application
│   └── Controller
│       └── IndexController.php
└── Less
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── Makefile
    ├── README.md
    ├── composer.json
    ├── docs
    │   └── docs.md
    ├── lessc.inc.php
    ├── lessify
    ├── lessify.inc.php
    ├── package.sh
    ├── plessc
    └── tests
        ├── ApiTest.php
        ├── InputTest.php
        ├── README.md
        ├── bootstrap.sh
        ├── inputs
        ├── outputs
        └── sort.php
```

Use class map in Application module **./module/Application/Module.php**

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Then generate **autoload_classmap.php**

```
<?php
// Generated by ZF2's ./bin/classmap_generator.php
return array(
    'Application\Module'                     => __DIR__ . '/Module.php',
    'Application\Controller\IndexController' => __DIR__ . '/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php',
    'lessc'                                  => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/lessc.inc.php',
    'lessc_parser'                           => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/lessc.inc.php',
    'lessc_formatter_classic'                => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/lessc.inc.php',
    'lessc_formatter_compressed'             => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/lessc.inc.php',
    'lessc_formatter_lessjs'                 => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/lessc.inc.php',
    'easyparse'                              => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/lessify.inc.php',
    'tagparse'                               => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/lessify.inc.php',
    'nodecounter'                            => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/lessify.inc.php',
    'lessify'                                => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/lessify.inc.php',
    'ApiTest'                                => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/tests/ApiTest.php',
    'InputTest'                              => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/tests/InputTest.php',
    'lesscNormalized'                        => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/tests/sort.php',
    'SortingFormatter'                       => __DIR__ . '/src/Less/tests/sort.php',
);
```

Finally, I can use it

```
public function compileLess()
{
    if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'production') {
        return;
    }
    $less_file = PROJECT_PATH . '/public/less/style.less';
    $css_file = PROJECT_PATH . '/public/css/style.css';

    $lessc = new \lessc($less_file);
    file_put_contents($css_file, $lessc->parse());
}
```

Comment: This may work, but it's not the best way to do it. Why not just use composer instead, which by the way you are probably already using since it's the preferred method to install zf2 in a project. Then the composer autoloader will take care of loading the library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the `Leafo` namespace in the autoloader. Let's say you have this tree:

```
MyProject
└── vendor
        Leafo
        └── Less
            ├── Lessc.php
            └── Lessify.php
```

Than you have to register the namespace like this:

```
    Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'autoregister_zf' => true,
            'namespaces' => array(
                'Leafo' => '/MyProject/vendor/Leafo',
            ),
        )
    ));
```

If you'r using the [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) you can change this in the `init_autoloader.php` file.

Comment: I've follow back their original structure `leafo/lessc.inc.php`, then I add the namespaces to `init_autoloader.php` i.e. `'leafo' => '/MyProject/vendor/leafo', when I call by `$lc = new \leafo\lessc`, it is not working